# Polynomial time approximation methods for TSP

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, np-complete, hamiltonian-path

I am aware that the Christofides algorithm is the best known polynomial-time algorithm for approximating solutions to the traveling salesman problem, but it only works for the metric TSP. Does anyone know the best polynomial-time approximation algorithm for the non-metric (but still symmetric) TSP? What about asymmetric TSP? Despite a lot of searching with Google, I have been unable to find this information online.

Comment: Recently a (just very slightly) better approximation algorithm for metric TSP than the one by Christofides was found by Gharan, Karlin and Klein.
For the ATSP there is a $(22+\varepsilon)$-approximation algorithm: [see here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.00670)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no known polynomial-time approximation algorithm for the non-metric TSP, even in the symmetric case. The existence of such an algorithm would imply P = NP, so there is good evidence that no such algorithm exists. This is because a non-metric TSP approximation algorithm would give a solution to the Hamiltonian cycle problem.

Suppose there was a function $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$, and polynomial-time algorithm which, given a complete weighted graph with $n$ vertices, outputs an $n$-vertex cycle whose weight is at most $f(n)$ times the optimal length cycle. Let $G$ be an arbitrary (unweighted) graph with $n$ vertices; we want to determine if $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle. Define a complete weighted graph, $G^*$, as follows.
$$
\text{weight}(u,v)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $u$ is joined to $v$ in $G$}
\\
n\times f(n) & \text{if $u\neq v$, and $u$ is not joined to $v$ in $G$}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that if $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle, then the optimal TSP cycle of $G^*$ has a weight of $n$, while if $G$ does not have a Hamiltonian cycle, then the weight of the optimal TSP cycle for $G^*$ is more than $n\cdot f(n)$. You can then use the purported approximation algorithm on $G^*$; if the outputted path has weight $n$, then $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle, and if the optimal path has weight more than $n\times f(n)$, then $G$ does not have a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: It may be worth noting that this reduction does not work for *all* functions $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. The reason for this is that the size of the weights might become arbitrarily large, and thus also the instance size. Hence, the size of the constructed TSP instance might not be polynomially bounded in the size of the Hamiltonian Cycle instance.
However, it still works for a lot of functions $f$, in particular $n \mapsto n$ proving that there is no constant factor approximation algorithm for general TSP unless $P=NP$.